# Breaking/opening files after failed jobs (sas7bdat.lck issue)

Tags: automation, sas

Good day,

Tl;dr: 
a) Is it feasibly possible to recover data from .lck file? 
b) If .lck issue appears, the SAS would work around it.

We have automated mundane jobs running on SAS machines. Every now and then job fails. This sometimes leaves locked file behind. (< filename>.sas7bdat.lck instead of < filename>.sas7bdat file)

This issue prevents re-running the program as SAS sees that there is already specified filename and tries to access it, failing. Message:

```
Attempt to rename temporary member of <dataset> failed.
```

Currently we handle them by manually deleting the file and adjusting generation number.

Question is two folded: a) Is it feasibly possible to recover data from .lck file? b) If .lck issue appears, the SAS would work around it. (Note that we have a lot of jobs and inputting checking code in all of them is work intensive.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.sas7bdat.lck` file is the one that SAS writes to as it's creating a data set. If the data step (or PROC) completes successfully, the original data set file is deleted and the `.sas7bdat.lck` file gets renamed to remove the `.lck` part. If any errors occur, the `.lck` file gets deleted and the original data set is left in place, unmodified. That's how SAS avoids overwriting existing data sets when errors occur.

Therefore, you should be able to just rename the file to remove the `.lck`, or maybe rename it to `damaged.sas7bdat` for example, and then try accessing the file. You can try a `PROC DATASETS REPAIR` (https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/proc/z0247721.htm) if you really need to get whatever data might be present.

The best solution will obviously be to correct whatever fault is causing your jobs to bomb out like this in the first place. No SAS program should ever leave `.lck` files lying about, even if it encounters errors - your jobs must actually be crashing the SAS environment itself, or perhaps they're being killed prematurely by another process. Simply accepting that this happens and trying to work around it is likely to just be storing up more problems for the future.

Comment: My thanks. Seems just what I'm after. I will certainly try this next time the issue emerges.